# Why rCharts does not return the figure?

Tags: rcharts

I try to use rCharts package to create interactive graphs. I used tutorials examples but I have not managed to use nPlot method. It did not return error but I did not receive the figure as they did in the tutorial.

```
require(devtools)
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
library(rCharts)

a<-as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)

hair_eye_male<-subset(a, Sex=="Male")
is.data.frame(hair_eye_male)

n1<-nPlot(Freq~Hair, group='Eye', data=hair_eye_male, type="multiBarChart")
n1


hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
p2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', 
            data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Female"), 
            type = 'multiBarChart'
)
p2$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'))
p2
```

in the Environment panel n1 and p2 appeared as Environment. I tried rChart and it works.
Best regards

Comment: are you using RStudio?  `nvd3` will not show up in the viewer of RStudio.  You will need to set `options(viewer=NULL)` or hit the button in viewer to open in your browser.

Comment: great, I guess I should also note for others reading this that the problem only happens in Windows.